# Appear ID and description in Dropdownlist ex: 1 - John

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have this code, only appears description, and i want to appear ID too, like:

```
1 - Easy
2 - Medium
3 - Hard
```

the code i have is:

```
Dim objDDL As New Challange.T

    Try
        FillDropDownListDS(ddlDS, objDDL.SelectResults(CurrentContext.CurrentUserId,      CurrentContext.CurrentCulture.idCulture), "desc", "id", True, True)


    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        objDDL = Nothing
    End Try

ddlDS.DropDown.SelectedValue = ParseDbField(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0), "id" + "desc")
.Tdropdown = ddlDS.DropDown.SelectedValue


Public Sub FillDropDownListDS(ByVal objCombo As DropDownListControl, ByVal DS As DataSet, ByVal TextField As String, ByVal ValueField As String, Optional ByVal BlankRow As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal clear As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal SelectIfUnique As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal SelectOldValue As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal concatValue As String = "") 
    FillDropDownListDT(objCombo, DS.Tables(0), TextField, ValueField, BlankRow, clear, SelectIfUnique, SelectOldValue, concatValue) 
End Sub
```

The FillDropDownListDT:

```
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim OldValue As String = ""

If Not IsNothing(objCombo) AndAlso objCombo.DropDown.Items.Count > 0 Then
        OldValue = objCombo.DropDown.SelectedItem.Value
    End If

    If clear = True Then
        objCombo.DropDown.Items.Clear()
    End If

    If BlankRow Then
        objCombo.DropDown.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", ""))
        objCombo.DropDown.SelectedIndex = 0
        objCombo.SelectedValue = objCombo.DropDown.SelectedItem.Value
        objCombo.SelectedText = objCombo.DropDown.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    For Each dr In DT.Rows
        Dim lit As New ListItem
        lit.Text = ParseDbField(dr, TextField)

        If concatValue = "" Then
            lit.Value = ParseDbField(dr, ValueField)
        Else
            lit.Value = ParseDbField(dr, ValueField) & "§" & ParseDbField(dr, concatValue)
        End If
```

Comment: Would you mind to show us `FillDropDownListDS`? Why don't you concat both columns with `+` like in `SELECT id + ' - ' + desc AS IdDesc FROM ...`?

Comment: Edit your question instead. Apart from that, show also `FillDropDownListDT`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  i already edit, thanks for your time!

Comment: Have a look at my comment and your code ;-)

Comment: "id" + "desc" you put "+"? i put that and dont do anything :(

Comment: You still haven't provided the code for `FillDropDownListDT`. Apart from that i don't understand _"i put that and dont do anything"_. Where have you used it?

Comment: i edit my question with FillDropDownListDT, what you edit in my code initially?